# Accessing one javascript class inside another

Tags: javascript, oop, underscore.js

I have two javascript “classes”. One of them is supposed to be a sort of general one, that will instantiate another sub-classes.

Somehow this throws an `undefined is not a function` error:

```
    this.progress = new Uploader.Progress({
      matcher: options.matcher,
    });
```

I'm using underscore as a dependency included through the Rails asset pipeline require statement. Here is the full code:

```
//= require underscore

if (typeof Uploader === "undefined") {
  var Uploader = {};
}

(function() {
  var Progress = Uploader.Progress = function(options) {
    options || (options = {});

    if(options.matcher) this.$matcher = $(options.matcher);

    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
  };

  _.extend(Progress.prototype, {}, {
    initialize: function() {
      this.listen();
    },

    listen: function() {
      this.$matcher.on("fileuploadprogress", function(e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        data.context.find(".upload-progress").css({ "width": progress + "%" });
      });

      return this;
    },
  });
})();

(function() {
  var Uploader = Project.Uploader = function(options) {
    options || (options = {});

    if(options.url) this.url = options.url;
    if(options.matcher) this.$matcher = $(options.matcher);

    this.progress = new Uploader.Progress({
      matcher: options.matcher,
    });

    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
  };

  _.extend(Uploader.prototype, {}, {
    initialize: function() {
      this.listen();
    },

    listen: function() {
      var _this = this;

      this.$matcher.fileupload({
        url: this.url,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",

        add: function(e, data) {
          data.context = _this.$matcher.closest("form");
          data.submit()
            .success(function(result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
              console.log("submitted");
            });
        },
      });

      return this;
    },
  });
})();

var uploader = new Project.Uploader({
  matcher: "#video_file",
  url: "/users/1/videos",
});
```

Comment: What line number is the JavaScript error originating from? Can we see the code that require's underscore.js?

Comment: Greg, the 39th line is causing the error (`this.progress = new Uploader.Progress({...`), underscore.js is being required on line 1.

Comment: Ok, I suspect the problem is within that fancy namespacing in `var Uploader = Project.Uploader = function(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say

```
this.progress = new Uploader.Progress({
      matcher: options.matcher,
    });
```

it matched the `Uploader defined in the`function scope` which is

```
var Uploader = Project.Uploader = function(options) {
```

and this one doesn't have a property `Progress` so `Uploader.Progress` is `undefined`. Hence, the error.

To fix that, change

```
var Uploader = Project.Uploader = function(options) {
```

To

```
var SomeOtherVariable = Project.Uploader = function(options) {
```

so now when you call `new Uploader.Progress({` it will start looking for `Uploader` outside the function scope as it will not find it within the function scope. The correct function set for `Uploader.Progress` in the global scope would be called.

Answer (score 1):

u create an uploader object on module scope

```
if (typeof Uploader === "undefined") {
var Uploader = {};
}
```

but then u create another local one

```
var Uploader = Project.Uploader = function(options) ...
```

binding anything on *this in the local object is not visible in the global one. that is a very strange style.